# How can I set AllowEmptyString on all entity framework's required attribute?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, ef-code-first

I have a project that use Entity Framework 6. I use approach "Code-Fist from Database". This is my generated entity:

```
public partial class DataProvider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my table definition:

```
| Column Name | Type           | Nullable   |
|-------------|----------------|------------|
| Id          | int            | false      |
| Label       | nvarchar(100)  | false      |
| Url         | nvarchar(1000) | true       |
```

I would that my generated entity was like this:

```
public partial class DataProvider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Actually, if I try to write empty string on Label the insert fail.

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: The `[Required]` attribute comes from the public non-sealed [`RequiredConfiguration`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EFTools/EntityDesign/CodeGeneration/Configuration/Property/RequiredConfiguration.cs) class, but it is detected using the internal [`RequiredDiscoverer`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EFTools/EntityDesign/CodeGeneration/Discoverers/Property/RequiredDiscoverer.cs) class, which suggests that there probably isn't a clean way to override it. Are you open to less clean options, or alternative methods for generating your classes?

Comment: Hi hvd, if I understand, I can override RequiredConfiguration class, is it correct? Thanks

Comment: Not quite what I wanted to say. You can override it, but if you cannot cause the overridden class to be used in place of the original, that won't do you any good. That's why I asked if you were open to alternatives.

Comment: I get it. If is possible, I would use default entity framework's instruments. Thank you a lot...